# Workflow monitoring self hosted and client connection

Tags: c#, workflow, workflow-foundation-4

Is it possible to do persistence and monitoring on self hosted Workflow ?
How would the client connect to the self hosted workflow ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Persistence works in self hosted workflows. Monitoring is done via the Tracking extension  which emits information about running workflows.  Not sure which "client" you mean.  My workflows tend to write to databases as part of what they do so I also write the Tracking information.  My clients read the database and act on the data they get.  You can also add WCF endpoints into your WFF app so the client can control the workflow or get the data directly.

Comment: thank you for your reply. by client I mean the MVC website which will want to call the Receive activities (operations). If the workflow is hosted in windows service forexample, how does the MVC call the operations of Workflow that are within windows service ?

Comment: I've never used the Receive activity so can't help you there.